# No funciona bien mi codigo de Javascript

Tags: javascript

He estado intentando hacer un *accordion* con javascript puro, lo había logrado pero mi código de la nada dejo funcionar bien, de las tres cajas solo funciona la primera, las demás antes funcionaban pero ya no, la consola no me da error. Ayúdenme a resolver este error o en su defecto decirme otra forma de hacer un *accordion* sin jquery ni bootstrap. Lo he intentando de todas las formas posibles pero todavía no he logrado hacer el *accordion*.

```js
var clic = 1;

function abrirCerrar(num) {
    var titulo = document.getElementsByClassName('titulo');
    var lista = document.getElementsByClassName('lista');

    if (clic==1) {
        clic = 0;

        lista[num].style.height = '100px';
        lista[num].style.opacity = '1';
    }
    else {
        clic = 1;

        lista[num].style.height = '0px';
        lista[num].style.opacity = '0';
    }
}
```

```css
.titulo {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.lista {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #111;
    width: 100px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    transition: height 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2 class="titulo" onclick="abrirCerrar(0)">Titulo</h2>
    <div class="lista">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2 class="titulo" onclick="abrirCerrar(1)">Titulo</h2>
    <div class="lista">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Con la propiedad display si me sirve el acordion, el problema es que no lo quiero hacer con diplay porque esa propiedad no tiene animacion

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @Rodrigo Corvera Díaz tienes un problema de diseño. La primera lista esta tapando el segundo `h2`, por lo que es imposible clicar en el. Ademas si quieres que sea un accordion, lo suyo sería cerrar todas las listas previamente abiertas.

Basicamente tienes que dejar el `height: 100px` siempre, eliminar la propiedad `opacity` y la propiedad que tienes que cambiar es el `display: none` por `display: block` cuando haces click.

```
.lista{
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

Snippet basado en tu código:

```js
    function abrirCerrar(num){
    var lista = document.getElementsByClassName('lista');

      for(x=0;x<lista.length;x++){
        lista[x].style.display = 'none';
      }
      lista[num].style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
.titulo {
   background: #444;
   color: #fff;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px auto;
  }

.lista{
  background: #ddd;
  color: #111;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h2 class="titulo" onclick="abrirCerrar(0)">Titulo</h2>
 <div class="lista">
  <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <h2 class="titulo" onclick="abrirCerrar(1)">Titulo</h2>
 <div class="lista">
  <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la forma en la que está estructurada la página, uno de los problemas que tienes es que la lista del primer `div` (cuyo valor de altura es 0px) al parecer se solapa con el botón de abajo, y no alcanza a reconocer el botón. Esto ocurre porque sigue ocupando el mismo espacio. Una sugerencia que te puedo dar es que pongas la  clase "lista" en los dos `<ul>` que tienes en la página. Lo que ocurre es que el contenedor tiene una altura de 0px pero la lista es independiente de ese valor, aunque no se muestre sigue estando ahí.